# json_query filter gives me invalid literal

Tags: jquery, json, ansible

i m having a json file  like this :

```
{
        "jcs-wls-2": {
            "componentType": "WLS",
            "creationDate": "2018-01-17T09:26:34.000+0000",
            "hostName": "jcs-wls-2",
            "id": 332687,
            "ipAddress": "144.21.79.147",
            "isAdminNode": false,
            "label": "JCS wls 2",
            "publicIpAddress": "144.21.79.147",
            "role": "MANAGED_SERVER",
            "shapeId": "oc3",
            "state": "READY",
            "totalStorage": 58368,
            "usageType": "MANAGED_SERVER",
            "uuid": "9B2984E9F90F42D588F779B28E339864",
            "vmId": 332687,
            "vmStateDisplayName": "Ready"
        },
        "jcs-wls-1": {
            "componentType": "WLS",
            "creationDate": "2018-01-17T09:26:34.000+0000",
            "hostName": "jcs-wls-1",
            "id": 332686,
            "ipAddress": "144.21.79.161",
            "isAdminNode": true,
            "label": "JCS wls 1",
            "publicIpAddress": "144.21.79.161",
            "role": "ADMIN_SERVER",
            "shapeId": "oc3",
            "state": "READY",
            "totalStorage": 78848,
            "usageType": "ADMIN_SERVER",
            "uuid": "DDE23E2801E24499912D12E552A60EC8",
            "vmId": 332686,
            "vmStateDisplayName": "Ready"
        }
    }
```

i want to iterate to every entry  `jcs-wls-1 ... jcs-wls-100` how this cloud be done ?

When i m trying to run a query to extract the jcs-wls-1 element like:

- set_fact:
     `servers: "{{ (wls_servers|json_query('[jcs-wls-2]')) }}"`

i m getting this error :

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in
>   json_query filter plugin:\ninvalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   '-'"}

I have tried some examples from the jmesPath tutorial but i cant make it work
If i remove the spaces of course this query runs
How can "escape" the - char , and iterate my json fiel ?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of all servers, use `json_query('*')`.

If you want to get specific server, use `json_query('jcs-wls-2')`.

Your original query (`[jcs-wls-2]`) make no sense, because you try to access indexed elements (within list `[]`) by name `jcs-wls-2` and not by integer index, so you get invalid `int()` conversion.

Comment: The query  "{{ wls_servers|json_query('jcs-wls1') }}"  still fails with  {"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\ninvalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'"}
The query json_query('*')  works
How should i treat the '-' char ?
Thanks Again :)

Comment: Seems like you have to quote it `"{{ wls_servers | json_query('\"jcs-wls-1\"') }}"`

Comment: Thanks  a lot  ... the escaping is working .. i still have a steep learning path for json  projects :)